# Raise vs raise up?

Tags: meaning, difference

**to raise a child.vs to raise up a child.**

I am unable to understand the difference between the two, what's the difference?(especially the use of"up")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Literal* uses of the verb ***raise*** - with the meaning ***elevate*** (to a higher level) - can often include preposition ***up***. But it's rarely included with the metaphorical sense ***bring to maturity***. Hence...

> 1: *We **raised** our children to respect authority* - FINE
> 2: *We **brought** our children **up** to respect authority* - FINE
> 3: *We **raised** our children **up** to respect authority* - NOT IDIOMATIC
> 4: *We **brought** our children to respect authority* -  UNGRAMMATICAL

Note that although we can *raise chickens on our farm*, nobody normally *brings up chickens on a farm* - both these metaphoric usages derive from essentially the same *literal* meaning, but ***bring up*** in this sense normally only occurs in the sense of caring for ***children*** from infancy to adulthood.